# Parse string using C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Need help in parse string using C# LINQ
I have a string like this

```
11=205129022,453=8,448=CompanyID,447=D,452=63,448=userid,447=D,452=11,448=CompanyName,447=D,452=13,448=W,447=D,452=54,77=O,555=2
```

I would like to split this string on `448=` then take an array start getting line "starts with 448" get the last string in the line which is `452=`
I'm trying this logic using LINQ to get the final output but it's not working.

```
var parties = rptstr.Split(new string[] { "453=" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(p => p.Split(new string[] {"448="},StringSplitOptions.None);

 var str448 = (from lnprty in parties 
                                   where lnprty.ToString().StartsWith("448=")
                                    //let tmp = line1.ToString() 
                                   select new PartyRoleModel()     
                                     {
                                         companyid == lnprty.Where(s => s.EndsWith("452=63,")).Select(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf('=') + 1)).FirstOrDefault(),
                     userid == lnprty.Where(s => s.EndsWith("452=11,")).Select(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf('=') + 1)).FirstOrDefault()  
                     companyname == lnprty.Where(s => s.EndsWith("452=13,")).Select(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf('=') + 1)).FirstOrDefault() 
                     PhyFlag == lnprty.Where(s => s.EndsWith("452=54,")).Select(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf('=') + 1)).FirstOrDefault() 
                                     })
                                .ToList();
```

I can split the line by `448` but `448` lines comes without `448=` since it got split, I need split string also in the line so I can identify the line.
Pls. remember the last line comes with other strings at end `(448=W,447=D,452=54,77=O,555=2)`.
I should get the final output like where 452=63 get companyid(which is in 447=), 452=11 get userid, 452=13 get companyname
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you give an example of what your desired end result would be?

Comment: I should get CompanyID for 452=63, userid for 452=11, CompanyName for 452=13 and W for 452=54. My values in 452 tag are fixed. The final outpu will be  strComID=CompanyID, strusrid=userid,strConme=CompanyName strflag=W.

Comment: Just prefix the split line(s) (i.e. all but the first from the split result) with whatever you split them by.

Comment: I tried prefix but my LINQ query "var str448 = ( from lnprty in parties" not getting methods Where,StartsWith, Endswith for lnprty.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string input = "";
            while ((input = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                //string input = "11=205129022,453=8,448=CompanyID,447=D,452=63,448=userid,447=D,452=11,448=CompanyName,447=D,452=13,448=W,447=D,452=54,77=O,555=2";
                List<string> strArray = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();

                //or dictionary
                Dictionary<string, int> rowDict = strArray.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '=' })).GroupBy(x => x.Last(), y => int.Parse(y.First())).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

                int id = rowDict["CompanyID"];

                dict.Add(id, rowDict);
            }

        }
```

Comment: In the line when I parse it i get the following lines,  each line is a group. 448=CompanyID,447=D,452=63,
448=userid,447=D,452=11,
448=CompanyName,447=D,452=13,
448=W,447=D,452=54,77=O,555=2

Comment: jdweng,pls discard my earlier comment.... In big string when I parse it by 448 I get following lines,  here each line is a group. 
448=CompanyID,447=D,452=63,
448=userid,447=D,452=11,
448=CompanyName,447=D,452=13,
448=W,447=D,452=54,77=O,555=2  

From these lines I want to get 448 value which is CompanyID for 452=63. when I separate long string by comma its difficult to find these group lines because the groups gets separated as individual string lines.

Comment: I think you may need a dictionary of Dictionaries Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,string>>

Comment: Jonathan, could you please give me the complete code. Thank you.

Comment: I update code to read multiple lines from a file and created a two layer dictionary.  I also reversed the int and string so the string is the key to the dictionary.